# Билдер для древовидной структуры данных?

Tags: java, c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Нужно реализовать паттерн билдер для древовидной структуры данных. Все что я пробовал, показывает, что это очень сложно делать и крайне неудобно намного проще сделать через несколько new.
Буду очень рад, если кто-то решал подобные проблемы и покажет пример такого билдера.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Допустим, мы хотим построить дерево. У нас есть узел

```
public class Node
{
    public int Value { get; set;}
    public Node Left { get; set;}
    public Node Right { get; set;}  
}
```

Далее пример fluent билдера. То есть вызовы можно объединять в цепочки, чтобы построить дерево

```
public class TreeBuilder 
{
    private InnerNode _root;
    private InnerNode _currentNode;

    private TreeBuilder(int value)
    {
        _root = new InnerNode() { Value = value };
        _currentNode = _root;
    }

    public static TreeBuilder Create(int value)
    {
        return new TreeBuilder(value);
    }

    public TreeBuilder AddLeft(int value)
    {
        _currentNode.Left = new InnerNode() { Value = value, Parent = _currentNode };
        return Left();
    }

    public TreeBuilder AddRight(int value)
    {
        _currentNode.Right = new InnerNode() { Value = value, Parent = _currentNode };
        return Right();
    }

    public TreeBuilder Left()
    {
        _currentNode = _currentNode.Left;
        return this;
    }

    public TreeBuilder Right()
    {
        _currentNode = _currentNode.Right;
        return this;
    }

    public TreeBuilder Root()
    {
        _currentNode = _root;
        return this;
    }

    public TreeBuilder Parent()
    {
        _currentNode = _currentNode.Parent;
        return this;
    }

    public Node Build()
    {
        return Build(_root);
    }

    private Node Build (InnerNode node)
    {
        if (node == null) return null;
        return new Node() {Value = node.Value, Left =Build(node.Left), Right=Build(node.Right)};
    }

    private class InnerNode
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public InnerNode Left { get; set; }
        public InnerNode Right { get; set; }
        public InnerNode Parent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Внутри билдера для представления не законченного дерева я использовал отдельный класс, так как этот класс имеет ссылку на родителя и с ним удобней ходить по узлам. По идее можно было накапливать информацию о строящемся объекта как понравится.

Ну, и, собственно, использование:

```
var root = TreeBuilder
            .Create(10)
                .AddLeft(5)
                    .Parent()
                .AddRight(15)
                    .AddLeft(10)
                    .Build();                       


//   10
//  /  \
//  5   15
//      /
//     10
```

Comment: Да, к такому решению пришел и я, только использовал метод end() вместо Perent(). 
Еще можно так :
and(
   or(1,2),
  and(3,2)
)

Answer (score 2):

Рискну привести исходники. Получилось довольно много кода:

```
private static class Team {
    public final List<Player> players;

    public Team(List<Player> players) {
        this.players = Collections.unmodifiableList(players);
    }

    public static TeamBuilder builder() {
        return new TeamBuilder();
    }

    static class TeamBuilder {
        private List<Player.PlayBuilder> playerBuilders = new ArrayList<>();

        public TeamBuilder add(Player.PlayBuilder builder) {
            playerBuilders.add(builder);
            return this;
        }

        public Team build() {
            List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Player.PlayBuilder playerBuilder : playerBuilders)
                players.add(playerBuilder.build());

            return new Team(players);
        }
    }

    static class Player {
        public final String name;

        Player(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public static PlayBuilder builder() {
            return new PlayBuilder();
        }

        static class PlayBuilder {
            private String name;

            public Player build() {
                return new Player(name);
            }

            public PlayBuilder setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
                return this;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Использовать так:

```
Team.builder()
    .add(Team.Player
             .builder()
             .setName("first player"))
    .add(Team.Player
             .builder()
             .setName("second player"))
    .add(Team.Player
             .builder()
             .setName("third player"))
    .build();
```

Основная идея - это создание для каждого объекта своего билдера, который бы потом передавался другому и так далее.

Comment: Так (c точки зрения интерфейса), например, реализованы билдеры в protobuf.

Comment: @ИванГладуш почему?

Comment: @ИванГладуш как так то? По мне так дерево, с вершиной `Team` и листами `Player`

Comment: Вы хотите дерево-контейнер с узлами одного типа произвольной глубины?

Comment: @Nofate да,я хочу именно это. Это древововидно, но не произвольной глубины