# Многоступенчатая обработка объекта во время инициализации C#

Tags: c#, архитектура

Натолкнулся на интересный пример инициализации объектов:

```
        Foo f = new Foo(16)
            .ChangeName("name")
            .GetString();

        f.ChangeName("wdqw");
        f.GetString();
```

Для такого подхода необходимо во всех методах класса возвращаемый тип привести к экземпляру этого класса:

```
class Foo
{
    int _number;
    string _name = "";

    public Foo(int number)
    {
        _number = number;
    }

    public Foo ChangeName(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Foo GetString()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Name - {_name}, Number - {_number}");
        return this;
    }
}
```

Смущает вот этот момент:

```
// Вот здесь вот получается возврат экземпляра класса вникуда )
        f.ChangeName("wdqw");
        f.GetString();
```

Собственно вопрос: Используется ли подобный подход в серьёзных конторах и не попахивает ли подобный код?

Comment: в таких случая лучше использовать публичные свойства (если я конечно правильно понял пример), фактически в шарпе инициировать такой класс можно при помощи свойств `var f = new Foo {number=16, Name ="wdqw"}`, но для этого класс Foo должен иметь вид: `class Foo{public int number {get;set;}  public string Name {get;set;}}`

Comment: Это называется [fluent builder](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/6.1.php), есть [разные сценарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/791635/179763) его использования

Comment: В Entity Framework этот способ широко [используется](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties).

Answer (score -1):

Используется. Например, в [Microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/71f8f57ac02d3652dc9e49fb0bb3e0f0919df04e/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/CSharpCompilationOptions.cs). Методы вида `WithTopLevelBinderFlags`.
Попахивает. Как и в случае любого другого паттерн, вам необходимо чётко понимать - для чего вы это делаете. В данном случае - для сохранения иммутабельности оригинальных экземпляров.

Что же касается приведенного вами примера, то он противоречит данному паттерну. Это должны быть чистые методы, которые НЕ изменяют внутреннее состояние оригинального объекта, а возвращают его клон (это может быть хитрое клонирование с CopyOnWrite, не обязательно новая структура в памяти). В вашем же случае, подход больше напоминает классический `StringBuilder`. И единственное его назначение - это создание таких вот цепочек:

`sb.Append("Hello").Append(' ').Append("World!");`

В этом случае, вам стоит обратить внимание на комментарий пользователя @Monomax.