# Объявление класса/структуры внутри другого класса: достоинства и недостатки

Tags: c#, .net, классы

В open-source проекте не раз встречаю объявление классов внутри другого класса. Почему программисты поступают так? Ведь можно просто создать папку в решении (расширить пространство имен) и добавить туда необходимые файлы с классами и структурами.

Пример такого объявления:

```
public class ClassContainer
{
    public const double SomeValue = 10;

    public class Foo { }
    public class Bar { }

    // ...
}
```

Может быть, существуют свои преимущества данного подхода?

**UPD.** Я, кажется, узнал причину, почему классы находятся внутри других классов. Дело в том, что часть проекта была **сгенерирована** из файлов исходного кода языка `с++` с помощью специального генератора кода, написанного на `Python`. Скорее всего, по этой причине классы обернуты еще одним классом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Вложенные классы имеют доступ к скрытым от внешнего мира членам класса уровня выше.
2. Можно спрятать какую-нибудь структуру внутри класса, если работа с ней снаружи не подразумевается и тогда эта структура не будет маячить в подсказках.

В приведенном вами примере, если не используется первым пункт, то смысла особого нету если конечно же нету задела на будущее. По факту в таком виде, внешний класс внутреннему является чем-то вроде пространством имен.

Comment: А как насчет protected полей? Ну и не только полей, но и свойств, методов, событий, конструкторов, индексаторов... в общем членов родительского типа.

Comment: @tym32167 подправил.

Comment: По поводу второго пункта, я как то писал [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/791635/179763), когда вложенный тип нужен для внутренней реализации класса, может автору будет полезно.

Comment: Еще [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/828845/179763), где вложенные типы реализуют публичный интерфейс.

Comment: Второй пункт - неплохое преимущество. Но вот в моем примере (как и в open-source проекте, который я сейчас разбираю) вложенные классы с модификатором `public`. Как я понимаю, это удобный для конкретного программиста вариант работы с пространствами имен через класс.

Answer (score 4):

> Почему программисты поступают так?

Сразу [пример](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646) в виде структуры `List<T>.Enumerator`. Вообще говоря, описание структуры внутри класса - вполне логичное решение при желании показать логическую связанность класса и структуры. С другой стороны - объявление `private/protected` классов или структур технически невозможно напрямую в пространствах имён, поэтому приходится оборачивать их во что-нибудь (например, класс).