# Класс, вложенный в класс

Tags: c#, ооп, вложенные-классы

Более опытные программисты, расскажите о реальных практических случаях, когда требовалось использовать класс, вложенный в класс. Просто не получается пока понять, зачем это может потребоваться.

Comment: А вас интересуют реальные примеры из реальной практики? Их есть, и много у кого. Только вот что вам даст, скажем так, субъективное объяснение? А объективно - если вы не чувствуете такой потребности - не используйте, делов-то. Как увидите, что надо - сразу поймёте, когда и зачем так делать.

Comment: к примеру, я в своей практике встречал дто , построенные с использованием вложенных классов. хорошо это или плохо - решать вам, но в целом выглядело довольно логично

Comment: Возможный дубликат: [Объявление класса/структуры внутри другого класса: достоинства и недостатки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/990227/212981)

Answer (score 2):

Из собственной практики, вложенные классы нужны как дополнительный способ инкапсуляции, чтобы "не выставлять наружу ненужный код", а использовать или нет эти возможности решать уже вам.

###### Один из примеров применения, это создание приватных наследников "внешнего" класса:

```cs
public class Outer
{
    public static Outer CreateSomething() => return new Inner();

    private class Inner : Outer { ... }
}
```

В данном случае `Inner` не будет виден за пределами `Outer` класса, позволяя скрывать внутреннюю реализвацию. Из практики было такое, например, у меня есть кастомная коллекция, которая реализует `ICollection<T>` назовем её `MyCollection` и у меня появилась необходимость расширить мою реализацию и добавить возможность сделать одну коллекцию родетелем другой, т.е. при вызове `myCollection[key]`, я сначала проверяю дочернюю коллекцию и созвращаю елемент, если его нет, тогда проверяю родительскую.

И есть несколько способов это реализовать:

- все запихнуть в один класс - плохо, получается каша и далеко не всегда эта фича с родитель-потомок отношением нужна
- создать нового **публичного** наследника `MyScopedCollection`, таким образом у меня появляется два класс, один в себе содержир реализацию коллекции, второй добовляет возможность добавлять её как родитель
- создать нового **приватного** наследника `MyScopedCollection`, аналогично предидущему пунтку, но дополнительно скрываем реализацию.

```
public class MyColletion : ICollection<...>
{
    // реализация коллекции

    public static MyColletion CreateChild(MyColletion parent)
        => new MyScopedCollection(parent);

    private class MyScopedCollection : MyCollection
    {
        public MyScopedCollection(MyColletion parent) { ... }
    }
}

// ...

var parent = new MyCollection { ... };
var child = MyColletion.CreateChild(parent);
```

###### Реализация паттерна [Memento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)

Этот паттерн позмоляет сохранить внутренне состояние объекта не раскрывая его, а потом при необходимости восстановить обратно. Можно использовать немного измененный пример из википерии:

```cs
class Memento
{
    private readonly string savedState;

    private Memento(string stateToSave) 
        => savedState = stateToSave;

    public class Originator
    {
        private string state;

        public void Set(string state)
            => this.state = state;

        public Memento SaveToMemento()
            => new Memento(state);

        public void RestoreFromMemento(Memento memento)
            => state = memento.savedState;
    }
}

// ...

var originator = new Memento.Originator();
originator.Set("State1");

var oldState = originator.SaveToMemento();

originator.Set("State2");
originator.RestoreFromMemento(oldState);

// originator.state == "State1"
```

`Originator` содержит некоторое состояние, а `Memento` позволяет сохранить его. Т.е. у `Memento` приватный конструктор, то создать "потдельное" состояние, а потом вызвать `RestoreFromMemento` не получится. Но в тоже время вложенные класс `Originator` имеет доступ к приватным членам внешнего класса. Поэтому мы может его созлать в `SaveToMemento` методе.

И теретически можно ещё придумать кучу примеров, но надеюсь эти примеры помогут вам понять когда можно использовать вложенные классы.

Answer (score 1):

В `C#` есть вариант реализации шаблона проектирования `Singleton` через вложенный класс, что позволяет сделать "ленивую" потокобезопасную инициализацию `instance`:

```cs
public class Singleton
{
    public string Date { get; private set; }
    public static string text = "hello";
    private Singleton()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Singleton ctor {DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay}");
        Date = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
    }

    public static Singleton GetInstance()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"GetInstance {DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay}");
        return Nested.instance;
    }

    private class Nested
    {
        internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Main {DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay}");
        Console.WriteLine(Singleton.text);
    }
}
```

Конструктор `Singleton` пока не вызвался, он вызовется при первом обращении к `Singleton.GetInstance()`.