Как правильно создать древовидную иерархическую модель на С#
В институте дали задание, разработать Древовидную иерархическую модель данных без ограничения уровня вложенности на любом языке программирования, но я не до конца понимаю что это и как это сделать, можете подсказать?
Я не прошу реализовывать всю модель, можно на псевдокоде или ссылкой, где создают что-то похожее

class Node { IList<Node> Children { get; } } — вот вам древовидная иерархическая модель данных без ограничения уровня вложенности

@АндрейNOP больше спасибо за ответ) Но не могли бы Вы объяснить что это значит? Модель Node у которой есть список самой себе, так?

Просто узел дерева описать? Тут есть пример + билдер https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/791635/179763
